# How to change or multiply the xticks by a factor in plt.acorr (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the autocorrelation function via `plt.acorr` of a time-series called `data`. The sampling rate of the recorded time-series is 2.16 seconds or 0.4629 Hz.

**Problem:** `plt.acorr` spaces the lags’ xticks in accordance to the sampling point sequence, meaning that each lag’s xtick on the x-axis corresponds to the numbers 1, 2, 3, and so on.

**Question:** Is there a possibility to change the xticks when using `plt.acorr` so that the xticks are evenly spaced starting from 0, over 1, to x ***in seconds***?

Or, if the above is not possible, would it be possible that the x-axis at least shows the real time difference (in seconds) between each time lag (see picture below)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [7.27958e-01, 6.59925e-01, 2.62454e-01, -1.73168e-01, 9.55694e-01,
2.25121e-01, 1.08360e+00, 3.71316e-01, -3.17764e+00, -1.15648e+00, -2.42453e+00]

plt.acorr(x=data, maxlags=None, normed=True, usevlines=True,
              color="blue", lw=2)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
plt.xlim([-0.1, 10])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `plt.xtick()` labels to show the numbers using the `np.arange()` as you did earlier but using 2.16 as the increment. Please see the code below. Note that we are only changing the x-axis labels. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = [7.27958e-01, 6.59925e-01, 2.62454e-01, -1.73168e-01, 9.55694e-01, 2.25121e-01, 1.08360e+00, 3.71316e-01, -3.17764e+00, -1.15648e+00, -2.42453e+00]
plt.acorr(x=data, maxlags=None, normed=True, usevlines=True, color="blue", lw=2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 11, 1), np.round(np.arange(0, 21.6001, 2.16), 2))
plt.xlim([-0.1, 10])
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: Maybe `np.arange(0, 21.6001, 2.16)` to include the last tick?

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, updated the answer. Was going off with ticks in the question :-)